# What are the draw back of having multiple smps stages in series?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, boost, efficiency, texas-instruments

**Application**

1. output - 100V 10mA
2. Input - single cell lipo 3.7V 5000mAh
3. overall efficiency > 85% required.

I tested Texas instruments power bench.

Texas instruments power bench cannot generate circuit for 2.8V-4.2V input to 100V 10mA output

my idea is to use two SMPS in series

stage 1, 2.8V-4.2V input to 9V 2A output @ 92% efficiency

stage 2, 9V input  to 100V 10mA output @ 87% efficiency

what can go wrong here or worst case scenario when stage 1 output is connected to stage 2 input?

Comment: Sounds like it should work ok, but 92% of 87% yields 79% efficiency. Not excellent but useful.

Comment: @Sparky256 you meant **Not excellent** but useful... is it because i was expecting overall efficiency > 85% and I get only 79%? or is there any other points to think about?

Comment: 0.92 x 0.87 = 0.80, or 80%.  There's not really any way around that.

Comment: 79% is good efficiency for two SMPS stages in a row. Total efficiency will always be less than the lowest efficiency supply.

Comment: @Sparky256 Also is this a standard or applicable or engineer's method to generate 100V 10mA? or is it the stupidest idea?

Comment: For this type of a use case, efficiency should probably be one of the last parameters you worry about. A large boost step like that voltage ripple on the output and voltage accuracy is probably more important depending on the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{You are focusing too much on efficiency as a parameter}}}$$

Consider the stage 1 circuit that you say can produce 9 volts at 2 amps with 92% efficiency. Consider how much current the stage 1 circuit needs to supply stage 2. Stage 2 delivers 100 volts at 10 mA as per this: -

> *output - 100V 10mA output @ 87% efficiency*

That's an output power of 1 watt and it means that your input power will be 1 watt ÷ 0.87 = 1.15 watts. That's an input current of 1.15 watts ÷ 9 volts = 128 mA.

Now, going back to stage 1 - it is stated that the efficiency is 92% when delivering 2 amps. However, when delivering 128 mA that efficiency is going to be much, much less. You can make a broad assumption that 50% of the losses when delivering 2 amps will still be present when delivering 128 mA. The losses in stage 1 delivering 2 amps are 18 watt × 0.08 = 1.44 watts so, 50% of that loss (0.72 watts) will still be present when delivering 128 mA.

So, rearranging things, stage 1 is delivering 9 volts at 128 mA = 1.15 watts and the overall input power to stage 1 is 1.15 watts plus 0.72 watts = 1.87 watts.

This makes stage 1's power efficiency 1.15 watts ÷ 1.87 watts = 61.5%. Hence why I said this early on: -

$$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{You are focusing too much on efficiency as a parameter}}}$$

The likely overall efficiency is going to be around 50% based on \$\color{red}{watt}\$ you have told us (the red spelling is my attempt at humour).

> *What are the draw back of having multiple smps stages in series?*

There are no real drawbacks in this case-example except you can probably achieve a better efficiency with a tailored flyback switcher design (circa 80% given your load and input voltage supply). Now I'm focusing on efficiency but justifiably so.

Comment: dumb question,, does amount of output ripple depend on efficiency of booster?

Comment: Yes it can do if the booster goes into a low power mode where it intermittently activates on low loads. It's called "burst-mode" and it usually produces more ripple on the output. It does this because the lack of load means it cannot properly regulate the output voltage in normal operation and has to find a way of preventing the output voltage rising excessively.

Answer (score 0):

Beat frequencies from different or slightly clocks. Can be dealt with through filtering with caps and ferrites or synching oscillators. This is also an issue in parallel converters as well.